# Data frame - R aggregate column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a csv with several columns,

> user_id,question_id,level, epoch and correct

It contains answers to question, I want to calculate the time for each question answer using the epoch time. I created a script that calculates the time for each question, but I want to aggregatte the time taked to the answer row in the data

```
 # Load file
data <- read.csv(file="D:/data.csv",head=TRUE,sep=";")

diff <- function(v) {
  return((v[2:length(v)] - v[1:length(v)-1]))
}

diffmean <- function(v) {
  return(mean(v[2:length(v)] - v[1:length(v)-1]))
}
#Time per answer and user
answerTime <- aggregate(data[,c("epoch")],
                        list(user_id = data$user_id),
                        diff)
 # Average response time
 meanTimePerUser <- aggregate(data[,c("epoch")],
                             list(user_id = data$user_id),
                             diffmean)
```

Comment: `1:length(v)-1` is identical with `0:(length(v)-1)` I suppose you don't want that.

Comment: Can you provide some input data and your expected results, eg. use `dput()`.